# The repository https://repo.bodar.com an error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: totallylazy

The library https://totallylazy.com/ has a reference for repo.bodar.com but we've a error in this DNS (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN). Somebody know what happen or alternatives?